# Safe fire and forget method in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, exception, thread-safety

I need to execute a **method** (not process) asynchronously in my Perl code, but I must ensure that this code will never raise any exception and stop my main task execution.

What would be the best way to call a method asynchronously and silencing any potential exception whether it is the called method internal exception whether it is an threading exception?

In Java we would had something like this:

```
// my task runs here
try {
    // assyncrounous method invocation (fire and forget)
    new MyThread().start();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // Silent any error
}
// my task continues here
```

Comment: What's wrong with `fork`?

Comment: That try catch is useless; it won't catch errors thrown by the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options if you want to execute arbitrary code asynchronously: You can run it in a separate process, or you can run it in a separate thread. Using a separate process would make even more robust, but you could use a thread.

```
use threads;
my $thread = async { code() };
```

`join` the thread to wait for it to finish.

Comment: An eval  block  would isolate  any exception?

Comment: No. Only after it completes.

Comment: How can it complete after throwing an exception?

Comment: If it throws  an exception  only the async code should stop. The "main" flow would continue.

Comment: So you do want the thread to exit. So no need to catch any exception.